# What happened to the ability to visualize query plans in a Databricks notebook?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, databricks, catalyst-optimizer

There is an old (year 2014) talk on [Youtube](https://youtu.be/GQSNJAzxOr8?t=1561) where the speaker visualized a query plan right inside a Databricks notebook. Here is the screenshot:

[image]

I am using databricks runtime 5.5 LTS ML and whenever I try to call `viz` on a query plan, I get this kind of error:

```
error: value viz is not a member of org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan
```

Has this feature been deprecated in Spark 2.0+ or do I need to install/import other libraries to get this feature?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is a visualization of it anymore, but they do explain SQL queries, which I think is what you are looking for.

```
spark.sql("your SQL query").explain(true)
```

or

```
yourDataframe.explain(true)
```